# If $A$ and $B$ are open then so is $A \cap B$. (+another related question)

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, proof-verification

If $A \cap B = \emptyset$ then $A \cap B$ is vacuously open.
If $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$ then since A,B are open, i.e $\forall z \in A \exists r>0 : D(z;r) \subset A $ similarly for B. we can find $z_0 \in A \cap B$ and $r >0$ such that $D(z_0,r) \subset A \cap B$. Hence $A \cap B$ is open.

Now what if $\mathbb{A}$ is a collection of open sets, then I need to show that $\cup A : A \in \mathbb{A}$ is open.

I think I have most certainly jumped the gun on this one.

Now let $z \in \cup A$ then $z \in A' $ for some $A' \in \mathbb{A}$ since $A'$ is open and $z$ was arbitrarily chosen...

I have just started learning complex analysis, although I think this comes under topology too.

My definition of open set:

*A set $K$ is open if for any $z\in K$ there exists an $r>0$ such that the open disk $D(z,r) \subset K$*

Comment: You should specify your definition of open (usually the definition is the thing you're trying to prove here, not whatever definition you're using, which likely only makes sense in metric spaces).

Comment: I think you have the right idea, though it could be written better.  For the intersection find a ball in $A$ and a ball in $B$ and then explicitly specify the ball with radius equal to the MIN of the two balls must be in $A\cap B$.  For the union it's even easier since if a ball is in any one of the collection then it's in the union.

Comment: For the union, your observation brings you close to the end, but probably you are expected to put in more detail (there is a disk which is a subset of $A'$ and hence of the union). For the intersection, the general idea is right, but you want to show that for any $z$ in the intersection there is an $r$ such that $\dots$. There is an $r_1$ for $A$ and an $r_2$ for $B$, so if you take $r=\min(r_1,r_2)$ then $\dots$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a topological space (X,T) :
a subset $A \subset X$ is open iff for any $x \in A$, A is a neighborhood of x; it means there is $O \in T$ (a open subset of (X,T)) such that $x \in O \subset A$.
In a metric space, we use open balls instead of elements of the topology T, and we get your definition.